# Adding a new variable with a code/formula that generates a moderate association with a previous one

Tags: r, tidyverse, simulation, generate

I try adding a new variable that has an association with the previous one. Is there a math/code trick/formula to increase the width of confidence bands in this association?

```
library(tidyverse)

d = tibble(a = rnorm(50, 100, 20))

#adding a new variable that correlates with the previous
d = d %>% mutate(b = a*10) #<- this is the formula

#plotting association
d %>% ggplot(aes(a, b))+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Comment: If you mean some kind of randomization of values, you might try the functions runif(), rnorm() and similar. To multiply your `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
d %>% 
mutate(b = a*10 + rnorm(50, 0, 100)) %>%
ggplot(aes(a, b)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]